# how can I use Sql Developer 4 to connect to sybase with net password encryption

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sybase, password-encryption

since the net password encryption settting has been turned on in Sybase server, i found I can't connect to sybase with SQL developer any more, any idea how to let my SQL developer connect to Sybase DB server with password encryption during the network transmission?

Comment: You need to check the docs for the specific driver you're using (e.g. JConnect, JTDs etc) and add the relevant parameter to pass in an ecrypted password. For example for Sybase's JDBC driver that would be ENCRYPT_PASSWORD.